# Simulating a mixed Poisson gives me fewer events than expected.

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, poisson-process, python, simulation

Referencing section 5.4.3 of the book, Introduction to Probability Models by Sheldon Ross (10th edition), the Mixed Poisson is introduced where the rate, $\lambda$ of a Poisson process is itself drawn from a Gamma distribution. Let this Gamma distribution we're drawing $\lambda$ from be described by $L$. On page 352 we get:

$$E(N(t)|L) = Lt$$

And so we get the intuitive result:

$$E(N(t)) = E(E(N(t)|L)) = E(L)t$$

I'm trying to replicate this with simulation. Let's start with a simple Poisson process. We use Python to simulate inter-arrival exponential distributions and stop when a total time of 1000 units has elapsed. When the rate, $\lambda=5$ per the code below, we get about 5000 events once 1000 units of time have elapsed. No surprises here.

```
import numpy as np
period=1000
evnts = 0
t=0
lm = 5
while t<period:
    t_del = np.random.exponential(1/lm)
    t+=t_del
    evnts+=1
print(evnts)
```

Now, I want to extend this simulation to a mixed Poisson as described in Ross. Instead of simulating from a fixed exponential every time, I first simulate the $\lambda$ parameter from a Gamma distribution. I confirmed that the Gamma used does have a mean of 5. I then use that $\lambda$ to simulate an exponential distribution. And the number of events in 1000 units of time drops to about 3000 instead of 5000 as expected from the equation above. What am I missing? Why should the number of events be smaller?

```
import numpy as np
period=1000
evnts = 0
t=0
while t<period:
    theta = 0.5
    lm = np.random.gamma(5*theta,1/theta)
    t_del = np.random.exponential(1/lm)
    t+=t_del
    evnts+=1
print(evnts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate a mixed Poisson you first generate a *single* Gamma variable $L$. This  value for $L$ gives you the $\lambda$ (rate) parameter, which you use for the duration of your Poisson process. In other words, you have to move the line

```
lm = np.random.gamma(5*theta,1/theta)
```

out of your `while` loop. When you do this, your event count will end up closer to the expected 5000.

Your current code is not simulating a Poisson process, since the interarrival times are not drawn from a single exponential distribution. Rather, each interarrival time is drawn from a *different* exponential, whose rate parameter $\lambda$ ranges from about $5-\sqrt{10}$ to $5+\sqrt{10}$ (these values are the mean $\pm$ standard deviation). Your code as written will generate many low values for $\lambda$ (which correspond to high interarrival times, which eat up a lot of the period) on virtually every run of your simulated point process; this is what causes the event count to drop. When you simulate properly, the low-$\lambda$ process will occur, but much less often, so low event counts are much less frequent.